# Foreach loop in combination with while(<>) "shifts" from @ARGV

Tags: perl

I have a simple assignment of creating a script that takes filenames as arguments, reads each line in each file and checks something.

I tried doing that like this:

```
foreach $file (@ARGV){
    while (chomp($line = <>)){
         ...
    }
}
```

And while I understand that while will simply read through all of the files, and that this approach is not good, I noticed that after each "foreach" iteration, @ARGV loses one entry, as if there was a

```
shift @ARGV;
```

It doesn't happen if there is no

That's the part that I don't understand, and would like an explanation. Why does @ARGV have 1 less element each time?

As an example, if I call the script with

```
./test.pl localhost_access_log*.txt
```

and there are files

```
localhost_access_log.2008-02-24.txt
localhost_access_log.2008-02-25.txt
```

in the current folder, after the foreach loop, @ARGV won't have both of them, but only one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

```
while (<>) {
    ...         # code for each line
}
```

is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:

```
unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
while ($ARGV = shift) {
  open(ARGV, $ARGV);
  while (<ARGV>) {
      ...       # code for each line
  }
}
```

> It really does shift the `@ARGV` array and put the current filename into the `$ARGV` variable. It also uses filehandle `ARGV` internally. `<>` is just a synonym for `<ARGV>`, which is magical. (The pseudo code above doesn't work because it treats `<ARGV>` as non-magical.)

Answer (score 4):

Reading from `ARGV` already loops through `@ARGV`, so your code makes no sense. Maybe you didn't know that `<>` means `readline(ARGV)`, `while (<>)` means `while (defined($_ = readline(ARGV)))`, and `while ($line = <>)` means `while (defined($line = readline(ARGV)))`. You should be using

```
while ($line = <>) {
    chomp($line);
    ...
}
```

`ARGV` removes from `@ARGV` as it opens them. For example,

```
print "Files to read: @ARGV\n";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print "Read $_ from $ARGV. Files left to read: @ARGV\n";
}
```

gives

```
$ script foo bar baz
Files to read: foo bar baz
Read foo1 from foo. Files left to read: bar baz
Read foo2 from foo. Files left to read: bar baz
Read bar1 from bar. Files left to read: baz
Read bar2 from bar. Files left to read: baz
Read baz1 from baz. Files left to read:
Read baz2 from baz. Files left to read:
```